# Как обновить страницу отправив GET запрос?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Задача такая:
Пользователь авторизован на сайте с пк и у него есть смартфон, или др устройство, необходимо отправить GET запрос с смартфона на сервер, после чего на авторизованном аккаунте (пк) необходимо вызвать модальное окно или любой другой интерактив. Вопрос: каким образом это можно реализовать? Делать запрос в бд c ajax каждые 1-3 секунды со стороны пк нормальное решение? Просто подскажите абстрактно как это реализовать и куда "копать".
Спасибо!

Comment: Запрос в бд через ajax каждые несколько секунд - решение плохое. Как вам уже написали - копайте в сторону WebSocket

Comment: @Pavel Krasulia поддерживаю про websocket, можно как пример посмотреть WhatsApp

Answer (score 1):

Нормальное решение - так vk делает.
Можно через websocket соединение.